# Getting the error I used ‘git config — global — unset https.proxy’ to get rid of the error but it doesn't work

Tags: go

I have installed go1.11/ windows amd64. I am testing the installation of GO

I installed golang with recommended path for all env variables but getting the errors while issuing 'go get github.com/golang/example/hello' on the command prompt

```
> `go get github.com/golang/example/hello
> # cd D:\gocode\src\github.com\golang\example; git pull --ff-only There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify
> which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.
> 
>     git pull <remote> <branch>
> 
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so
> with:
> 
>     git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> master
> 
> package github.com/golang/example/hello: exit status 1`
```

Below is my output of 'go env':

> > go env set GOARCH=amd64 set GOBIN= set GOCACHE=C:\Users\parapand\AppData\Local\go-build set GOEXE=.exe set
> >     GOFLAGS= set GOHOSTARCH=amd64 set GOHOSTOS=windows set GOOS=windows
> >     set GOPATH=D:\gocode set GOPROXY= set GORACE= set GOROOT=C:\Go set
> >     GOTMPDIR= set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64 set GCCGO=gccgo
> >     set CC=gcc set CXX=g++ set CGO_ENABLED=1 set GOMOD= set CGO_CFLAGS=-g
> >     -O2 set CGO_CPPFLAGS= set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2 set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2 set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64
> >     -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\parapand\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build101474458=/tmp/go-build
> >     -gno-record-gcc-switches
>
> `>go build 
>   can't load package: package .: no Go files in C:\Users\parapand`

Comment: try `go get -u github.com/golang/example/hello`. If this fails. Delete `example` directory in `d:\gocode\github.com\golang\`

Comment: Did you made some changes in the local downloaded package (`D:\gocode\src\github.com\golang\example`)?

Comment: Michael D  it did not work either :  >go get -u github.com/golang/example/hello
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/golang/example D:\gocode\src\github.com\golang\example
Cloning into 'D:\gocode\src\github.com\golang\example'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/golang/example/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
package github.com/golang/example/hello: exit status 128